# Python 3.3 tkinter's Entry widget update on key

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, python-3.3

I am using `tkinter` for a GUI. I bound an event to an entry like so:

`EntryFilePath.bind("<Key>", updateAmountOfPeople)`

It works, but the problem is that it only updates when a key other than typing input is being pressed. Backspace triggers it, arrows trigger it, just not letters or numbers. I am looking for this functionality.

Other info that might be important:

```
PathFileName = StringVar()
EntryFilePath = Entry(topLeftMidFrame, textvariable = PathFileName, width=45)
EntryFilePath.pack(side=TOP, pady=32, padx=10)
```

How to make it trigger on any key?

**EDIT:** I found out that this only happens when it just got selected. It needs one of the "other" non [a-Z0-9] keys once, after that it is good to go. This is problematic though, in case people start immediately writing.

**EDIT2:** It might have to do with it having update delay.

Comment: That _ought_ to work, based on info given; widget-specific bindings should fire before class-level bindings. Tkinter bug perhaps?

Comment: @DonalFellows I realized the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The binding should work for every keypress -- if it's not, you're doing something somewhere else in your code to prevent it from working, or your testing is flawed.

If you want a function to be called whenever the value changes, you might want to consider setting a trace on the variable associated with the entry widget. The trace will fire whenever the value changes, no matter whether it's through keyboard input, pasting with the mouse, etc. It will *not* call your callback when the user uses the arrow keys or the return key, or any other key that doesn't affect the value.

For example:

```
def var_callback(*args):
    print "the variable has changed:", PathFileName.get()
PathFileName.trace("w", var_callback)
```

Comment: So what does actually happen when you change the variable, it calls that callback function? The trace on "r" triggers when something uses .get() on the entry?

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by changing

```
EntryFilePath.bind("<Key>", updateAmountOfPeople)
```

to

```
EntryFilePath.bind("<KeyRelease>", updateAmountOfPeople)
```

Comment: Ah! You wanted the post-edit value. Try looking at postponing the operation until the application is “idle”, or (better yet) turning on per-key validation.